# Drupal link add description using l

Tags: drupal

How can I add description in link button in Drupal7 by using "l()".  Please give with example.

Answer (score 1):

If by description you mean title of the link then go for the following solution. Say you want a link with name `LINK_NAME` to point to `http://<yoursite>/user`, the following line gives you the same.

```
l('LINK_NAME', '/user', array('attributes' => array('title' => 'Title'));
```

Comment: Almost...the options array needs to be `array('attributes' => array('title' => 'Title'))`